# Erro 1067 ao executar o Apache 24

Tags: php, mysqli, apache

Acabei de configurar o PHP7 no Apache 24 e estou a tentar executar o apache vem o erro 1067.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O5UG.png)

Tentei alterar a configuração do PHP no arquivo config do Apache mais não resultou